# Command that only displays ip address and subnet mask using ifconfig

Tags: grep, pipe, ifconfig

I need help with my Linux laboratories. Does anybody know a combination of command complies with this exercise?

*Look at the output of /sbin/ifconfig. Write a line that only displays IP address and the
subnet mask. (use head; grep; tr -s; cut; )*

This what is what I got so far:

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep -w "inet"
```

Comment: Homework works best if you solve it yourself. What is your expected output?

Comment: Honestly speaking I have no idea. I think it is supposed to be something like _address mask_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would acheive the desired effect

`/sbin/ifconfig | grep -Po '(?<=\binet )[^/]+/\w+|(?<=\binet6 )[^/]+/\w+'`

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. In the end, I used it to write this command: `/sbin/ifconfig | grep -P '((?<=\binet )[^ ]+)|((?<=\bnetmask )[^ ]+)' | head -1`. Without your help I would stuck forever.

Comment: I was guessing `ifconfig`'s output was the same as `IP address show`, obviously it's not. sorry @Krystofer125

Comment: No problem, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame you can't use awk

```
ifconfig -a eth0|grep -w inet |awk '{print $2, $4}'
```